# SQLAlchemy connection to database: What could it be now?

Tags: python, sql-server, database, sqlalchemy, database-connection

I am trying to connect to a database I made in SQL Server through SQLAlchemy and I'm Having trouble printing the table 'Empleados'. I suspect it might be my connnection URL. Something might be wrong with it. I've tried running the code without the "# execute the query and print the results" part and it doesn't throw any mistakes. Help is appreciated.

`

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select, Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, text, URL

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://login1:1234@BLADESTEALTH/myDatabase?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server")

# create a metadata object
metadata = MetaData()

# define the table structure
Empleados = Table('Empleados', metadata, 
                  Column('Cedula', String, primary_key=True),
                  Column('Nombres', String),
                  Column('Apellidos', String))

# define a select query
stmt = select().select_from(Empleados)

# execute the query and print the results
with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(stmt).fetchall()
    for row in result:
        print(row)

`
```

I tried many different ways to build my connection URL but it never worked.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try the URL below and see if it works.

`engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://login1:1234@BLADESTEALTH:1433/myDatabase?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server")`

If not, validate the following items in the checklist:

1. SQL server is actually up and running using any SQL server management
2. Your program is able to resolve hostname BLADESTEALTH correctly
3. Try using telnet and use this command to make sure everything is working telnet BLADESTEALTH 1433
4. You are using the default port for SQL Server which 1433

Hope this helps and you get your code working.